# Received memory warning. Level=1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Hi friends i am working on Location Finder Application in which everytime when i goes into Map page i get Warnings Like :

```
"Received memory warning. Level=1"
```

After that application crashes no idea what to do please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It seems you have memory leak in your code. Please use instrument and find out memory leaks.

Comment: Better to start using ARC..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means you have very serious memory leaks. So you will want use instrument - memory leak to find them and fix them. A good thing to do before that is go to your xcode menu, Product - Analyze to find all the obvious memory issues first.

Sometimes you can also try set up break points to figure out where the crash come from if the results from the Analyze and instrument - memory leaks doesn't make much sense.

No matter what I guess you have to learn how to use instrument. You cannot get away with it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have build, Analyze & remove all memory leaks still its continuously gives memory warnings so what to do ?

Comment: Are the memory warnings totally random or you get them up to the certain point? Can you narrow it down so that you know where they are triggered(i.e: are they happened in the middle of view load or happened when the user interact with a certain ui control... etc). If you can narrow it down and post your code, I will take a look at it.

Comment: Actually it comes random & it comes only when user goes in to Map view  & try to Zoom in & out to see certain ragion

Comment: I never used map view before, but if you can post your code, I would certainly take a look and try to find the problem. Another good place to go if you have registered as a Apple iOS developer is their technical support. If you are a registered developer, you can get free 2 times support from apple, "Whether you need direct one-on-one support troubleshooting issues, hands-on assistance to accelerate a project, or helpful guidance to the right documentation and sample code, Apple engineers are ready to help you." So after you log in to member centre, select Technical under Developer Support.